# How to get a textarea parent with jQuery

Tags: jquery, textarea, parent

I have this situation:

```
<div class='postit_popup' id='xxx'>
   <div style='margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px;text-align:justify;'>
      <textarea class'txtNota'>some text</textarea>
   </div>
   <div class='clear'></div>
   <div style='margin-left:20px;' align='left'>
      <img class='okNota' src='img/ico/task-completed.png' height='20' width='20'>&nbsp;
      <img class='cancewlNota' src='img/ico/button_cancel.png' height='20' width='20'>
   </div>
</div>
```

I need to get content in the textarea when there is a click on the image with class "okNota".

I did it in this way:

```
$(".okNota").click( function() {

   var obj = $(this).parent().parent();

   alert(obj.children(0).children(0).val());
});
```

But I need to know if there is another way to obtain it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$(this).parents(".postit_popup").find("textarea").val();
```

Or if you have more than one textarea in `.postit_popup` then use:

```
$(this).parents(".postit_popup").find(".txtNota").val();
```

What this does is traverse up the DOM from `.okNota` until `.postit_popup` is found and then it goes back down the DOM to find a `textarea` or an element with the `.txtNota` class.

Comment: the first method works fine but not the second. But is not important. The first method works better then mine...

Comment: See my answer. In this case, "closest" is more appropriate that "parents".

Comment: Yeah, perhaps. As long as the `.postit_popup` divs aren't nested within each other this will be fine. But yeah just incase; `closest` instead of `parents` would be more fitting.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help: http://jsfiddle.net/vgtQR/

EDIT (for JohnP)

HTML

```
<div class='postit_popup' id='xxx'>
   <div style='margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px;text-align:justify;'>
      <textarea class='txtNota'>some text</textarea>
   </div>
   <div class='clear'></div>
   <div style='margin-left:20px;' align='left'>
       <div class='okNota'>OK Image</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.okNota').click( function() {
   alert($('.txtNota').val());
});
```

Comment: Please post the code in this answer. This helps keep the information in one place :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".okNota").click( function() {     
var value = $('.txtNota').val();
 });
```

This will work. You are missing '='.

```
<textarea class = 'txtNota'>some text</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$(this).closest(".postit_popup").find("textarea").val();
```